# c# Lock Bitlocker Encrypted Drive

Tags: c#, cmd

I Have the following C# code to lock a particular drive using Bitlocker. I am using the Windows Command Prompt command : `manage-bde -lock G:`(the drive I want to lock). However, my drive still remains unlocked at the end of Program.
My Code:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C manage-bde -lock G:";
        startInfo.Verb = "runasuser";
        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Might not fix the issue, but you shouldn't need to wrap `manage-bde` in a call to `cmd`. Try just `startInfo.FileName = "manage-bde"; startInfo.Arguments = "-lock G:";` Also try `Verb = "runas"` to run as administrator, rather than just another user.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is that utility: `runasuser`?
   I know just `runas`.

`startInfo.Verb = "runas";`

2. There is an issue in x64 environment:

> In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64

So, you need to call `manage-bde` in that way:

`startInfo.Arguments = "/C %windir%\\sysnative\\manage-bde -lock G:";`